# How to solve $a=x \lfloor x \rfloor$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can I solve for $x$ given $a=x \lfloor x \rfloor$

Where $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, and where $a$ is a rational number.

What I've done

\begin{align}
\frac{a}{x} &= \lfloor x \rfloor \\
\implies \frac{a}{x} & \le x < \frac{a}{x}+1 \\
\end{align}

which yields two cases

\begin{align}
\sqrt{a} &\le x \quad (1) \\\\
\left(x+\frac{1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}\right) \left(x+\frac{1-\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}\right) &< 0 \quad (2)
\end{align}

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Compare the graphs of $x\cdot \lfloor x\rfloor$ to $x^2$.  You should be able to see that there are values of $a$ for which no such $x$ exists.  You should also be able to see that by knowing the value of $a$, you should be able to figure out the value of $\lfloor x\rfloor$, and from there you will be able to calculate $x$ itself.

Comment: I know that I could solve it like that, but I wanted to know if it could be solved analytically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lfloor x \rfloor = n$, you want $x = a/n$ and $n \le a/n < n+1$.  Thus (assuming $n > 0$)
$n^2 \le a < n^2 + n$.  Now $(n+1)^2 = n^2 + 2 n + 1 > n^2 + n$.  So:

Given $a \ge 1$, 
take $n = \lfloor \sqrt{a} \rfloor$.  If $a \ge n^2 + n$ there is no solution.
Otherwise, $x = a/n$.